# How are type-bound procedures linked to their derived types in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, name-mangling, derived-types

Coming from C++, I know that non-virtual member functions are tied to their classes through name-mangling. I'm trying to learn modern Fortran and my question is how are Fortran type-bound procedures linked to their types?

For example, consider the derived type

```
module shape_mod

    type shape
        integer :: color
        logical :: filled
    contains
        procedure :: isFilled
    end type shape

contains

    logical function isFilled(this)
        class(shape) :: this
        isFilled = this%filled
    end function isFilled
 
end module
```

My question is about the internals of procedure dispatch. Does the memory layout of an instance `shp` of type `shape` hold a pointer to a function or vtable that needs to be de-referenced when calling `shp%isFilled()`, as happens with virtual member functions in C++? Or is the name of the type-bound procedure `shp%isFilled()` mangled into something like `_Z5shape_isFilled(shp)`, as happens with non-virtual member functions in C++?

I know that Fortran uses name mangling for procedures in modules [see wiki for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Fortran).

Comment: a valid question and I wish I knew the answer.

Comment: If you have gfortran, you can look under the hood at what it is doing.  Try compiling your code with -fdump-tree-original.  nm or objdump may also be of some help.

Comment: AS for C++ it's going to be compiler dependent. Why do you want to know this? Just curiosity? Thinking about how a compiler would implement something as opposed to what the standard actually says is not always the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

### **There is no need for (additional) name mangling here at all.**

The procedures you write are completely ordinary normal module procedures. They just have a polymorphic dummy argument. You do not have to call them as type-bound, you can use them in a normal way.

What makes them type-bound is the creation of the binding in the type declaration.

```
 procedure :: isFilled
```

that means there will be a virtual table and a pointer to the procedure in the virtual table and so on and it will point the right type-bound procedure for the right actual type.

But the procedures are completely ordinary ones. At least conceptually, I did not study the compiler, I am describing the standard concept.

In your case you can call

```
   type(shape) :: instance

   print *, isFilled(instance)
```

and it will work perfectly fine, there is nothing special about the procedure itself.

Note that when you are extending the type

```
type, extends(shape) :: outlined_shape
    integer :: outline_color
contains
    procedure :: isFilled => isFilled_outlined shape
end type shape
```

you have to use a different name for the procedure. Hence no name mangling is necessary, you already have a procedure with a different name

```
logical function isFilled_outlined_shape(this)
        class(outlined_shape) :: this
```

Again, you can call it as a type bound procedure:

```
type(outlined_shape) :: instance

print *, instance%isFilled()
```

but you can also call it directly (non-virtually)

```
  print *, isFilled_outlined_shape(instance)
```

and you can even call the parent one directly

```
 print *, isFilled(instance)
```

The reason why C++ needs name mangling is because it uses the same name fir the virtual function in each type. It does not have these normal procedures that have different names as in Fortran. Because if that, C++ needs name-mangling.

---

Consider this example:

```
module m

  type t1
  contains
    procedure :: s => s_t1
  end type

  type t2
  contains
    procedure :: s => s_t2
  end type
  
contains

  subroutine s_t1(self)
    class(t1) :: self
  end subroutine

  subroutine s_t2(self)
    class(t2) :: self
  end subroutine

end module
```

In gfortran, the result contains these symbols:

```
000000000000000f T __m_MOD___copy_m_T1
0000000000000000 T __m_MOD___copy_m_T2
0000000000000000 B __m_MOD___def_init_m_T1
0000000000000001 B __m_MOD___def_init_m_T2
0000000000000029 T __m_MOD_s_t1
000000000000001e T __m_MOD_s_t2
0000000000000000 R __m_MOD___vtab_m_T1
0000000000000040 R __m_MOD___vtab_m_T2
```

their meaning is the following:

```
0000000000000029 T __m_MOD_s_t1
000000000000001e T __m_MOD_s_t2
```

the subroutine, you can call them directly this way (non-virtually).

```
000000000000000f T __m_MOD___copy_m_T1
0000000000000000 T __m_MOD___copy_m_T2
```

the intrinsic assignments of the two types.

```
0000000000000000 B __m_MOD___def_init_m_T1
0000000000000001 B __m_MOD___def_init_m_T2
```

the default constructors of the two types

```
0000000000000000 R __m_MOD___vtab_m_T1
0000000000000040 R __m_MOD___vtab_m_T2
```

the virtual table functions, one per type (not per procedure, it is not name-mangling of the procedures).

When you add more procedures, https://godbolt.org/z/3q4KWf you can see how the virtual tables contains pointers to them:

```
__m_MOD___vtab_m_T1:
        .long   69979407
        .zero   4
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   __m_MOD___def_init_m_T1
        .quad   __m_MOD___copy_m_T1
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   __m_MOD_r_t1
        .quad   __m_MOD_s_t1
__m_MOD___vtab_m_T2:
        .long   69979408
        .zero   4
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   __m_MOD___def_init_m_T2
        .quad   __m_MOD___copy_m_T2
        .quad   0
        .quad   0
        .quad   __m_MOD_s_t2
        .quad   __m_MOD_r_t2
```

Comment: I appreciate you pointing directly to the assembly (can't believe it didn't come to my mind). You said "*The reason why C++ needs name mangling is because it uses the same name fir the virtual function in each type.*" But C++ uses name mangling for non-virtual methods, namespaces, function overloading, template specialization, etc. Fortran also uses uses name mangling. But I don't see why C++ non-virtual methods use name mangling, but Fortran type-bound procedures use vtable indirection.